# creationPolicy="all" for states in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

There is such thing in `ViewStack` as `creationPolicy="all"`, is there the same thing for states? My goal is to set some attributes for one state, while the other one is active.

Comment: States have a completely different implementation than ViewStacks and creationPolicy does not apply.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on why exactly you want to do this. It might help us come up with a solution to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a 1 to 1 correlation, however there are some things that can be done in a "similar" fashion. It largely depends on what you are trying to set, but remember visual components won't even be initialized/created during an inactive state. I usually go about this in two ways.

1. Create a StateChangedEvent listener to know when to react to a particular state - this is especially true if you use some 3rd party framework to separate the view (ie not writing behaviors in the mxml itself).
2. You can write a state to be 'basedOn' another state, meaning you can create some quasi-inheritance chain for states. This might be useful if you have 2 states which share a lot of the same visual representation, in which case the base state will be active for "both" since it is not re-initialized between the two.